# How to mock Publish/subscribe events on React Components when using PubSubJS with Jest/Enzyme?

Tags: reactjs, jestjs, publish-subscribe, enzyme

I have the following code:

```jsx
class Dummy extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    this.state = { field: '' }
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    PubSub.subscribe('event', () => {
      this.setState({ field: 'a' });
    });
  }
}
```

I want to make sure that when I Publish `event`, the state is set to `a`. How do I achieve this using Jest with Enzyme?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

PubSub provides `publish()` and `publishSync()`:

- `publishSync()` [calls `deliver()` synchronously](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS/blob/8ed94f97b0bcb68967a77ea92867b068e224e516/src/pubsub.js#L128).
- `publish()` [uses `setTimeout()`](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS/blob/8ed94f97b0bcb68967a77ea92867b068e224e516/src/pubsub.js#L130).

You can either use `publishSync()` or use fake timers with `publish()`.

---

`publishSync()`

```jsx
test('should subscribe to event', () => {
  const component = shallow(<Dummy />);
  expect(component.state('field')).toBe('');
  PubSub.publishSync('event');
  expect(component.state('field')).toBe('a');
});
```

---

`publish()` and `Jest` [Timer Mocks](https://jestjs.io/docs/en/timer-mocks):

```jsx
test('should subscribe to event', () => {
  jest.useFakeTimers();  // wrap timer functions in mocks

  const component = shallow(<Dummy />);
  expect(component.state('field')).toBe('');

  PubSub.publish('event');
  jest.runAllTimers();  // run all timer callbacks

  expect(component.state('field')).toBe('a');
});
```

---

PubSub uses both [`publishSync()`](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS/blob/8ed94f97b0bcb68967a77ea92867b068e224e516/test/test-publish.js#L32-L44) and [`publish()` with `Sinon` fake timers](https://github.com/mroderick/PubSubJS/blob/8ed94f97b0bcb68967a77ea92867b068e224e516/test/test-publish.js#L84-L99) in its own tests.

Comment: Hey Brian , Can you please tell me or answer me how to solve the same issue in Angular context https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64151027/jasmin-unit-test-cases-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read-property-classlist-of